# In a multi-column grid, how to limit the number of items in each column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on a seamless responsive grid using the css property column-count and I want to display 5 columns with a limit for each column to have equal number of items (for example limit to 4 items per column), but cannot find such property in css.

[image]

Comment: I recommend to use `masonry` http://masonry.desandro.com/v3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Jquery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

**What is Masonry?**

Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

How to use:

```
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```